# Parse json data categorywise in sencha touch

Tags: json, parsing, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

for my sencha touch app my json data like this,

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": "rodos_business_pois.1",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      28.21962354993591,
      36.452844361147314
    ]
  },
  "geometry_name": "geom",
  "properties": {
    "id": null,
    "business_p": "AQUARIOUM",
    "name_owner": null,
    "surname_ow": null,
    "middle_nam": null,
    "category_n": "BAR",
    "category_c": "020200",
    "category_1": null,
    "category_2": null,
    "category_3": null,
    "address": "28 GRIVA GEORGIOU",
    "street_nam": "ÃÑÉÂÁ ÃÅÙÑÃÉÏÕ",
    "number": "28",
    "postcode": null,
    "places_en_": "RODOS",
    "f16": 1,
    "f17": 0,
    "tel": 2.24102778E9,
    "fax": 0,
    "mob": 0,
    "email": null,
    "url": null,
    "places_gr": null,
    "places_en": null
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": "rodos_business_pois.2",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      28.225417523605692,
      36.436470953176716
    ]
  },
  "geometry_name": "geom",
  "properties": {
    "id": null,
    "business_p": "ZIGOS",
    "name_owner": null,
    "surname_ow": null,
    "middle_nam": null,
    "category_n": "BAR",
    "category_c": "020200",
    "category_1": null,
    "category_2": null,
    "category_3": null,
    "address": "89 KAZOULI STEFANOU",
    "street_nam": "ÊÁÆÏÕËÇ ÓÔÅÖÁÍÏÕ",
    "number": "89",
    "postcode": null,
    "places_en_": "RODOS",
    "f16": 1,
    "f17": 0,
    "tel": 2.24103987E9,
    "fax": 0,
    "mob": 0,
    "email": null,
    "url": null,
    "places_gr": null,
    "places_en": null
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": "rodos_business_pois.3",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      28.223100266167258,
      36.45251556942936
    ]
  },
  "geometry_name": "geom",
  "properties": {
    "id": null,
    "business_p": "LA ROSA FASHION BAR",
    "name_owner": null,
    "surname_ow": null,
    "middle_nam": null,
    "category_n": "BAR",
    "category_c": "020200",
    "category_1": null,
    "category_2": null,
    "category_3": null,
    "address": "4 PAPANIKOLAOU GEORGIOU",
    "street_nam": "ÐÁÐÁÍÉÊÏËÁÏÕ ÃÅÙÑÃÉÏÕ",
    "number": "4",
    "postcode": null,
    "places_en_": "RODOS",
    "f16": 1,
    "f17": 0,
    "tel": 2.2410974E9,
    "fax": 0,
    "mob": 0,
    "email": null,
    "url": null,
    "places_gr": null,
    "places_en": null
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": "rodos_business_pois.4",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      28.226588152300117,
      36.43403310824089
    ]
  },
  "geometry_name": "geom",
  "properties": {
    "id": null,
    "business_p": "G-NET",
    "name_owner": null,
    "surname_ow": null,
    "middle_nam": null,
    "category_n": "RESTAURANT",
    "category_c": "020100",
    "category_1": null,
    "category_2": null,
    "category_3": null,
    "address": "135 AGIAS ANASTASIAS",
    "street_nam": "ÁÃÉÁÓ ÁÍÁÓÔÁÓÉÁÓ",
    "number": "135",
    "postcode": null,
    "places_en_": "RODOS",
    "f16": 1,
    "f17": 0,
    "tel": 2.2410351E9,
    "fax": 0,
    "mob": 0,
    "email": null,
    "url": null,
    "places_gr": null,
    "places_en": null
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": "rodos_business_pois.5",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      28.215719877096184,
      36.43079419827729
    ]
  },
  "geometry_name": "geom",
  "properties": {
    "id": null,
    "business_p": "ANDRMEDA LOUNGE BAR",
    "name_owner": null,
    "surname_ow": null,
    "middle_nam": null,
    "category_n": "CAFE",
    "category_c": "020100",
    "category_1": null,
    "category_2": null,
    "category_3": null,
    "address": "4 PAPANDREOU GEORGIOU",
    "street_nam": "ÐÁÐÁÍÄÑÅÏÕ ÃÅÙÑÃÉÏÕ",
    "number": "4",
    "postcode": null,
    "places_en_": "RODOS",
    "f16": 1,
    "f17": 0,
    "tel": 2.2410974E9,
    "fax": 2.2410975E9,
    "mob": 0,
    "email": null,
    "url": null,
    "places_gr": null,
    "places_en": null
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": "rodos_business_pois.6",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      28.226209613062103,
      36.43806195312573
    ]
  },
  "geometry_name": "geom",
  "properties": {
    "id": null,
    "business_p": "DOLCE CAFE",
    "name_owner": null,
    "surname_ow": null,
    "middle_nam": null,
    "category_n": "RESTAURANT",
    "category_c": "020100",
    "category_1": null,
    "category_2": null,
    "category_3": null,
    "address": "14 DODEKANISIAKIS NEOLEAS",
    "street_nam": "ÄÙÄÅÊÁÍÇÓÉÁÊÇÓ ÍÅÏËÁÉÁÓ",
    "number": "14",
    "postcode": null,
    "places_en_": "RODOS",
    "f16": 1,
    "f17": 0,
    "tel": 2.24102988E9,
    "fax": 0,
    "mob": 0,
    "email": null,
    "url": null,
    "places_gr": null,
    "places_en": null
  }
},
.......
.......
....... and so on..
```

i can parse all these data at a time using sencha touch json reader,
but now i want to parse this data by category wise, means
at a time i want to parse all  those data which have category  like **BAR** or **CAFE** or **RESTAURANT**.

any help will be appericiated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to read all and filter it, or else modify the API so that you pass the specific category and get the JSON accordingly

Comment: can you suggest good filter example or suggestion about how to modify API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you filter the store

```
store.filterBy(function(record, id){
    var cat = record.get('category_n');
    if(cat == 'BAR' || cat == 'CAFE' || cat == 'RESTAURANT'){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

This will iterate each record and will pass it in function, so if you want to check for category_n

EDIT: make sure you clear the store filter next time you load data into the store by

```
store.clearFilter();
```

Comment: thanks.., in record field i can get all data, but stuck there, i can't go ahead.
can you give me some more explanation ?

Comment: Record will contain element from ur json array and it will iterate one by one.. from your recordmatch the ccondition on which u want to filter.. if u return true that element will be available in ur store if u return false then it will be removed from store...

Comment: i can't get it, becoz it throwing error during getting properties using  record.get('properties').
and throwing error like this,
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'prop.get')

Comment: thats more reasonable and expected, console.log(record); and check if properties is in there? i'm expecting it should have type and feature

Comment: can u please paste whole json so that it would be good to figure out coz the json you have posted is incomplete, also the reader you using in proxy to read this, may be we have to put one more filter on first place

Comment: here is my whole json,
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://geodata-server.com/geoserver/Rhodes/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Rhodes:rodos_business_pois&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=json

Comment: in record i can get properties like this,

   PropertiesBelongsToInstance: Object, 
   _data: Object, 
   data: Object
   address: null
   business_p: "CAZA DI FLABIA"
   category_n: "RESTAURANT"

Comment: i have edited my ans.. please check, by the time i look at ur json

Comment: i have already tried that one before, but didn't get category.

Comment: can u host on to sencha fiddle

Comment: actually it's bit harder to host whole code on sencha fiddle.

Comment: i can get id and type by record.get('id') and record.get('type'), but can't get properties or category_n.

Comment: try record.get('data').get('category_n')

Comment: or log in first in two ways.. console.log(record.get('data')); and console.log(record.data.get('category_n'));

Comment: finally i found solution, i can get category by record.PropertiesBelongsToInstance.get('category_n')... :)
Thanks @mayur for driving me in right direction. i have updated your answer.